# What's the best way to sync variables with UI controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a C# desktop application with lots of variables in the code that are visible and controlled within the UI. The values of these variables are also saved in application settings, and often modified throughout the application's logic.

My question is, what would be the best practice to keeping values within UI controls in sync with the values of these variables regardless of where or how these variables are modified? To be more specific, I'd like the UI controls to reflect the values of the variables at all times, without having to modify the values inside those UI controls manually. I'm referring to textboxes, checkboxes, dropdownlist selections, etc...

Update: I'm using WinForms

Comment: Which UI, WinForms or WPF or something else?

Comment: [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) in WPF and [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding) in WinForms

Comment: We need more information. This question is too board. Are you you creating a web application, mobile, desktop?

Comment: Thanks I've updated my question with these details.

Comment: Are other users accessing the data at the same time?  Is that the "sync" part?

Comment: In my imagination just put your controls to panels based on how they are related then control the visibility from panels. Otherwise, you need to be more specific and give us instances instead of concept.

Comment: Add those variable to a *Manager* class as properties. Use a `BindingSource` and add `Bindings` to the controls to automatically update all class properties that are bound to controls' properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I'll change the variables' value in the changed event of the control.

- On the TextChanged event of a textbox
- On the SelectionChanged of Combobox.
- On the CheckChanged of Checkbox or Radio Button

Example:

```
string str;

public void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   str = textbox1.Text;
}
```

The moment something is changed/modified on any of its control, then it updates the variable value.